# How can I remove unused code from a nx workspace project libs (Most libs are in Angular - typescript)?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, code-cleanup, nx-workspace

We already have set up eslint rules (no-unused-vars) to detect unused vars and also unused imports.
What we are struggling to find is unused components, state management codes, css styles and unused service methods.

I am trying to find a command / package which will scan through all our codebase and find these unused codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run this command:

```
npx depcheck
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck

I just tried it yesterday, because my coworker mentioned it. As far as he told me, it checks package.json for unused dependencies, but I saw that it listed out some components for me as well. I think it's quite close to what you are looking for.